# How to extract MachineReading entity mentions and MachineReading relation mentions

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am working with Stanford's NLP API and I made a StanfordCoreNLP object:

```
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

And these are the properties for the `pipeline` object:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner, parse, dcoref, relation");
    props.put("ner.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
    props.put("regexner.mapping", "locations.txt");
    props.put("regexner.ignorecase", "true");
```

And I annotated this simple text using the `StanfordCoreNLP` object:  "I love chocolate. I bought chocolate cake."

I got the result, but at the end of each sentence, this is what I got:

> Extracted the following MachineReading entity mentions:
>   Extracted the following MachineReading relation mentions:

There was nothing after these entity and relation mentions. They were blank. So my question is, how does this work? How do you get a relation/entity mentions? And what is MachineReading and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

This link should help for the code http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.structure.RelationMention

You have to use the Named Entity Recognizer and the Relationship Extraction appropriately to get the expected results.